# Java displaying error of special characters with data from Mysql with custom collation (as, ci) for utf8

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, collation

I have set up a custom collation for utf8 characters in Mysql. This collation is Accent Sensitive and Case Insensitive, which I need. But these Characters with accents are not displayed well in my Java application. What do I have to do to get these characters displayed the right way?
When I use a default utf8 collation of Mysql like utf8_general_ci, there is no problem but when I use my own collation there is...

Below is the java code to get the data from mysql:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqlmoviesdb";
        String connectionUser = "";
        String connectionPassword = "";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID, Title FROM mymovies Order By Title");
```

Comment: Can you share your connection string?

Comment: show us your code first :-)

Comment: Not well displayed? Try `string = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFC);` - maybe MySQL splits a Unicode ŝ into s^, and has bad rendering in the used font. My code would Compose them again to one single Unicode symbol. Or better check the chars / int code points in the string.

Comment: MySQL gives only 2 choices:  Accent and case sensitive (_bin) or Strip accents and ignore case (_ci).

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be related on how data are stored in the database or in which format they are shown, i ll suggest you to check if the database char format is set to UTF8 and if the client which displays data is set on UTF8 too, by the way i am not sure if you mean that the collation fails cause the retrieved information are not the same as ones in database (for special chars problem) or they are just not being displayed in the correct way in the application after the collation is done